# Multiprocessing fails to pickle top level functions

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pickle

I am trying to parallelize my task and decided to use the multiprocessing (mp) module.
I have soon learnt that mp can't handle nested functions, so I had to unnest a function similar to this:

```
def foo(nomer1, nomer2):

    def bar(nomer1, nomer2):
        return ([nomer1] * nomer2)

    return(bar(nomer1, nomer2))
```

to this:

```
def bar(nomer1, nomer2):
    return([nomer1]*nomer2)

def foo(nomer1, nomer2):
    return(bar(nomer1, nomer2))
```

However, when I run:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
n_proc = 2
pool = mp.Pool(processes=n_proc)
pool.starmap(foo, [11, 2])
```

The console produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 274, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 424, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function foo at 0x00000189D37902F0>: attribute lookup foo on __main__ failed
```

Foo is on top-most level, as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled), but mp still fails to pickle it.
How can I solve this, preferably w/out installing additional packages?

Comment: This may be relevant https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1252

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, using `concurrent.futures`
This package should goes with my Python installation and the issue is resolved as easily as:

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
future = pool.submit(foo, 11,2)
print(future.result())
```

The error seems to be a result of [a known bug](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/ptpython/issues/193). The suggested Anaconda update doesn't help, though. I wonder if this bug is still present after a year of being reported.

Meanwhile, future's `ProcessPoolExecutor` produces a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 234, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda2\envs\env1\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function foo at 0x000001D816CF5510>: attribute lookup foo on __main__ failed
```